# Java Graph's nodes representation

Tags: java, graph, variable-assignment

So I have to build this for my assignment, where I am given an input file that creates a graph using `x` and `y` coordinates like:

```
(1,3)
(4,4)
(5,10)
```

etc...(thats the input in the file)

Afterwards, I then give the user the option to do DFS/BFS where they then input the start and goal coordinates for this. I have created an adjacency matrix before where my nodes (vertices) are `A`, `B`, `C` etc but I have never used coordinates similar to this one as my nodes.

**My question is**: how do I represent these coordinates as nodes in a graph...I know an adjacency matrix won't work in this case and I need something different (due to there being no max size), but I'm completely confused about how to represent these coordinates as nodes at the moment. Can someone help me?

**Additional info [from comments]:**

each pair represents an edge between the two, so (1,3) has an edge/connected to (4,4) and (5,10) would be connected to the next pair given underneath (that I did not write up), we can assume the input is correct/is even in pairs

Comment: I assume your coordinates are the vertices. what are your edges? is the graph a clique?

Comment: @amit sorry, I forgot to mention that, each pair represents an edge between the two, so `(1,3)` has an edge/connected to `(4,4)` and `(5,10)` would be connected to the next pair given underneath (that I did not write up), we can assume the input is correct/is even in pairs

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map your coordinates, each coordinate will have an integer representing it, and the integers should be continious [0,1,2,...,n-1] where n is the number of coordinates.

Do it by first iterating on the coordinates, and insert each new coordinate to the map with a new integer.

This way, you can create an adjancy matrix, because you know exactly how big your graph is [remember, you counted it, so you just found the number of nodes, which is the matrix's size!]

Now you can easily create a matrix, refer to each coordinate as an integer. An edge in the matrix is like always, if there is an edge: p1,p2, you should set `matrix[map.get(p1)][map.get(p2)] = 1`